# Fourier Series and Uniform Convergence

Tags: analysis, fourier-series

This question is an extension of [Fourier series simplification](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1187331/80327)

I know wish to show $$(\frac{1}{\pi})\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^2(x) dx = a_{0}^{2}/2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_{n}^{2} + b_{n}^{2})$$
But, we no longer have the help of uniform convergence. In detail, we have $f:[-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ a piecewise smooth function.

We cannot approach the problem as we did in the previous exercise since we relied on uniform convergence of the Fourier series. How then should we approach the problem? I had found https://www.math.ubc.ca/~yhkim/yhkim-home/teaching/Math257/M257-316Notes_Lecture16.pdf but this assumed uniform convergence.

It is quite simple with uniform convergence, but again, we do not have that luxury.

Clearly we have $$\langle f(x),f(x)\rangle = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)^2dx$$ but from here?

Comment: What does "smooth" mean?

Comment: @snarski http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothFunction.html

Comment: It's Parceval identity (for Fourier series). Can you use it, or do you need to prove it?

Comment: What I wrote about is Parceval's Identity (I thought), so I need to prove it.

Comment: This has been proved before on this site (try to search for "Parseval proof"). See for example [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741986/proof-of-parsevals-theorem-for-fourier-series) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8648/explain-below-part-of-the-proof-of-parsevals-relation) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437073/parsevals-theorem-proof). You might have to search a bit to find a question with the exact conditions you need though.

Comment: @Winther I did, but did not find any questions that did not use complex forms of $f$.

Comment: See [this note](http://www.ima.umn.edu/~miller/fourierseries.pdf) Theorem 6 and Corollary 2 on page 20.

Comment: @Winther Since $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$, is it okay that $f$ is complex in Theorem 6 and Corallary 2?

Comment: Yes exactly, a real-valued function is a complex-valued function (but the converse is of course not true).

Comment: Great. We have our solution by Corollary 2 then. Quite a bugger that is so long though.

Comment: Yes there are some details there that makes it very long, but thats not so important imo. The important thing is to try to understand the idea behind the proof. If you understand this you can always reconstruct the boring details with some work if needed.

Comment: @Winther At the top of page 22, it says that f converges uniformly. Do you know how they reached that?

Comment: This is basically theorem 5 page 15. Note that $f$ is continuous on the set $A$ (by definition).

Comment: Ah. Okay. I wish there was an explanation of the motivation of the proof. I'm having a hard time understanding.